# Custom Items control Approach

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need to build a custom items control in WPF, where the user can drag/drop the items. Normally I would just maintain a list of view models and use a data template to define how the items should be displayed (in this case, a button). But I am concerned that this will make the drag/drop difficult as the ItemsSource objects will be view model objects , not the actual button.

My other potential approach is when an object is added to the ItemsSource, create a button in c# and add it manually, that way I can access the button directly to do drag/drop.

What would your advice be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue. I found a way to get the control being render from the data template